# how to dom table in simple html dom in php?

Tags: php, dom

hi i have this html code and i want to get the 76.000.000.000 data on that.
i search the div#TopBox but it shows nothing.(means no children found on it)
html code:

```
<div id="TopBox">
<div id="divSupervision" style="color:#800040;font-size:12px;vertical-align:middle;">
</div>
<div class="box2 zi1">
   <div class="box6 h80">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Total</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="ltr inline" title="76,000,000,000">76 B</div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my code :

```
$html = str_get_html($curl);
$div = $html->find("div#TopBox");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's a problem with 'str_get_html' function, it seems the method from WP, but you can get this data using RegExp:

```
preg_match('/title="([\d,]+)"/', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the div inside `div#TopBox` and get its attribute `title`:

```
$html = str_get_html($curl);
$total = $html->getElementById("TopBox")->find('div.inline')[0]->getAttribute('title');
echo $total; // 76,000,000,000
```

Note that you might test the length of array before accessing elements (`[0]`).

Comment: tnx man.i use your code but it shows err bcoz dom has a null data.Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Answer (score 0):

this code work on local html

```
$html = file_get_html("file.txt");
$total = $html->getElementById("TopBox")->find('div.inline')[0]->getAttribute('title');
echo $total; // 76,000,000,000
```

but when i use it to fetch data online it doesn't work why?

Comment: can any one help me? i really need it and can't do this .